# Calling 2 non-async functions, but while function 1 is processing, function 2 should start

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency

I have 2 functions:

```py
def funca():
    do_somethhing()
    call_some_api()


def funcb():
    do_somethhing()
    call_some_api()


funca()
funcb()
```

After calling `funca()`, while `funca()` is still processing, is it possible to call `funcb()`?

Condtion: Calling the function should not be asynchronous. After calling `funca`, that should immediately trigger `funcb`, while `funca` is processing. I can not make the functions asynchronous because `funca` and `funcb` are not under my control.

Comment: You seem unfamiliar with basic concepts of concurrency, so I'll just drop two hints for you: 1) Threads 2) Processes. If you cannot use `asyncio`, those two approaches may be viable. Since it sounds like you are doing I/O (requests to some API?), [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) may be the better choice. If `funca` and `funcb` do CPU-bound work, better use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: I have a doubtt, the other service calls functA and after completing process of functA(functions are defined  in my service that I handle), it will call funcB, Then can I say the other service, that call funcB with out completing the process of funA.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg From your point, the functioncall should be in threard, then it will call two functions at  a time with out depending on other.

Answer (score 1):

> I can not make the functions asynchronous because `funca` and `funcb` are not under my control.

Sounds like you need to use someone else's code, but want to make the two tasks run concurrently.  If the two functions are IO bound (which is the case for most API calls), then you can start each function within a thread.  The `concurrent.futures` module is a great option.  Just following the example from the documentation:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as ex:
    futures = {ex.submit(fn): name for fn, name in [(funca, 'A'), (funcb, 'B')]}
    results = []
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        name = futures[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
            results.append({'name': name, 'data': data, 'error': None})
        except Exception as err:
            results.append({'name': name, 'data': None, 'error': err})
```

Both `funca` and `funcb` are run concurrently, but any code after the `with` statement is blocked until both functions return.  Here I added the results as dictionaries to the `results` list, but you can use whatever structure you want to store the results.